# Integrating Dash and Flask by inserting Dash chart into div block of Flask template

Tags: python, html, flask, plotly-dash, dash-leaflet

My team is currently working on a project but recently we've got the following problem. To begin with, we're creating a website via `Flask`. We've already done a lot of work and have some nice `html` templates. However, the thing is that now we need to add `Dash` map  (to be more precise, `Dash Leaflet` but I strongly believe that they're quite similar) to the certain `div` block of our page. Unfortunately, we have no idea how to realize it...

So, we already have a structured and designed `html` template for the page. As it was said above, the only thing we need to do is to insert `Dash` map into the certain div block:

```
...
<body>
    ...

    <div class="map">
    
        <!-- ??? ??? ??? ??? ??? ??? -->
        <!-- ???   Your Dash map ??? -->
        <!-- ??? ??? ??? ??? ??? ??? -->
    
    </div>
    
    ...
</body>
...
```

We have no ability to recreate the website as we have a lot of created things which would be quite sad and disappointing to rewrite:(

How can we integrate `Flask` app and `Dash` by inserting map to the certain `div` block? Is there any easy solution for this?

Comment: Why don't you just generate the map itself in `folium` and scrap the `dash` dependency?

Comment: Or use `leaflet` directly in JavaScript, as I do in my own website. Using `dash` here really isn't going to do you any favours

Comment: @roganjosh We want to use exactly `Dash` because a part of our team has already created tools for working with it and interacting with user. I'm not quite sure that they will be happy with recreating all the stuff. But still great thanks for advice!

Comment: That's unfortunate because mixing flask and dash is not going to be easy. `folium` will give you the HTML and you could try recreate the functionality around it. There is [at least one guide](https://hackersandslackers.com/plotly-dash-with-flask/) that shows it's difficult enough just for baseline functionality - I wouldn't wanna be facing up to map integrations

Comment: @roganjosh Thank you! I'll wait for some other answers but you helped us too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some folks in the comments have suggested, using leaflet.js directly is a cleaner approach to doing this. One thing to bear in mind is that if you go down the Dash route, you're dependant on the dash-leaflet library continuing to be maintained and updated supporting new versions of Leaflet.

But if you've got folks who've already put some effort into building a Dash Leaflet app then can totally see why you'd wanna at least explore whether getting them to play together is viable.

If you want to place the Dash app in a `<div>`, I suspect the best way is probably just to use an `<iframe>` that points to the endpoint your app is running.

Conveniently, Dash uses Flask under the hood, so a trick you might find handy is that you can get your existing Flask server to serve your Dash app under a specific path, by passing the Flask server instance to your `Dash` instance's `server` param, and setting the `url_base_pathname` param to a prefix to mount the Dash app at. Here's a simple example:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask

from dash_app import make_dash, make_layout, define_callbacks

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"

dash_app = make_dash(app)
dash_app.layout = make_layout()
define_callbacks()
```

**dash_app.py**

```
from dash import Dash, html, callback, dcc, Input, Output


def make_dash(server):
    return Dash(
        server=server,
        url_base_pathname='/dash/'
    )

def make_layout():
    return html.Div(                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        [                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            html.P("Hey this is a Dash app :)"),                                                                                                                                                                     
            dcc.Input(id="input"),                                                                                                                                                                                   
            html.Div(id="output"),                                                                                                                                                                                   
        ]                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    )

def define_callbacks():
    @callback(
        Output("output", "children"),
        Input("input", "value"),
    )
    def show_output(text):
        return f"you entered: '{text}'"
```

When you navigate to `/`, you'll see the Flask route, and navigating to `/dash` will show you the Dash app. You could either have users go directly to the Dash URL, or use that path as the location of the iframe if you need to embed it within an existing page.

Comment: Thank you for such a good answer -  we did something quite similar and it works great!

Comment: great to hear!!

Comment: I have begun trying this out and it worked. The IFRAME approach appears to offer a clear separation between Flask and Dash.  I am yet to scale this for a more complex Dash layout - but I think it should work.  Nice!  Any pitfalls I should be aware of ?